# Enrich device life cycle events Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I need to enrich the device life cycle events[Created, Deleted, Connected, Disconnected] received on Event Grid.
The event flow in my solution is like below:-

`Device send registration request to IoT Hub -> Event grid triggers device life cycle event -> Event grid routes device life cycle event to Event Hub`.

Since my application i.e. consumer to Event hub only that is the reason I'm routing all events to Event Hub from Event Grid.
Now, I need to enrich the event received on Event hub. For example, the device connected event should look like below:

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "id": "58b1872d-1388-8043-dacc-6322ca65d2bf",
      "topic": "SOME_TOPIC",
      "subject": "devices/diablo-central-park-1",
      "eventType": "Microsoft.Devices.DeviceConnected",
      "data": {
        "deviceConnectionStateEventInfo": {
          "sequenceNumber": "SOME_SEQ_NUMBER"
        },
        "hubName": "IOT_HUBNAME",
        "deviceId": "DEVICE_ID"
      },
      "dataVersion": "",
      "metadataVersion": "1",
      "eventTime": "2020-10-16T06:33:42.2418032Z"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "aeg-output-event-id": "SOME_ID",
    "aeg-subscription-name": "SOME_NAME,
    "aeg-delivery-count": "0",
    "aeg-data-version": "",
    "aeg-metadata-version": "1",
    "aeg-event-type": "Notification",
    "enrichedProperty": "enrichedValue"
  },
  "offset": "25769816448",
  "sequenceNumber": 2197,
  "enqueuedTimeUtc": "2020-10-16T06:33:49.321Z",
  ""systemProperties": {}
}
```

So, In above event JSON, I should get the `enrichedProperty` in the properties field. I have done message enrichment for twin change events, telemetry through Message routing(Enrich Messages)in IoT hub blade on the portal. But for device life cycle events I could not find a way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a very similar manner. So you create an end point (e.g. a storage container), then create a route making sure you choose "Device Lifecycle Events" in the data source of the route. then go to "enrich messages" tab and add the name and value of the property that you want , making sure the correct end point is selected. Also make sure that the root is enabled and the route query is true. Now when you create or delete a device, your events will be captured and the enriched property will appear in the captured event properties.

Comment: Device connected and disconnected doesn't directly come on Event Hub(EH). Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369985/iot-hub-message-routing-with-devicelifecycleevents-source-does-not-work/64420097#64420097.So the event needs to be routed to EH through Event Grid. Now there is no way to enrich the message from event subscription created through Events.

Comment: you are right. I was suggesting your route directly without event grid , but that will only work on device create and delete